# Using '@notfound_view_config' in Pyramid with 'renderer'

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm unable to get my specified template to render when using [@notfound_view_config](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/view.html#pyramid.view.notfound_view_config) as described in [Pyramid Docs - Using Hooks](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/hooks.html).

views.py:

```
@notfound_view_config(renderer='templates/notfound.pt')
def notfound(request):
    return Response('Not Found, dude', status='404 Not Found')
```

templates/notfound.pt:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      metal:use-macro="base">

<tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">

            <!-- Example row of columns -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                   <h1>Error:</h1>
                   <p>Uh, oh... you snagged an error:</p>
                   <pre>"${request}"</pre>

                   <p>You can return to the <a href="${request.application_url}">homepage</a> if you wish.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

</tal:block>
</html>
```

When hitting a page that doesn't exist, I see the message "Not Found, dude" on a blank page, but I expected to see my template with "Uh, oh... you snagged an error!" followed by the request information.

I suspect I'm reading this wrong:

> The notfound_view_config constructor accepts most of the same
>   arguments as the constructor of pyramid.view.view_config. It can be
>   used in the same places, and behaves in largely the same way, **except
>   it always registers a not found exception view instead of a ‘normal’
>   view.**

On one hand, it seems like I should be able to specify 'renderer' as a parameter since it's supported in pryamid.view.view_config.  On the other hand, it sounds like it's always loading the [not found exception view][3], regarless of the 'renderer' option.

Really, my ultimate question (and goal) is, how do I display/render my template whenever a page is not found?

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/views.py#L1892) clearly handles a renderer, so this should Just Work. Try changing the returned dict in the view to make 100% certain you didn't mix up registrations or a restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The renderer-view relationship is always the same in Pyramid. If you return a Response object, then your declared renderer is bypassed. This allows you to do things like `if submitted: return HTTPFound(location=...) else: return {}`. If you'd like to affect the response object and still use your renderer, then return the required dict and mutate `request.response`, the response object that is used for all renderers.

```
@notfound_view_config(renderer='templates/notfound.pt')
def notfound(request):
    request.response.status = 404
    return {}
```